# Drupal Site accessible to Mobile

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, mobile-website

I have some 20 sites with common codebase and database via Drupal Multisite installation.
Whats the best way to make a multisite Drupal installation also accessible via mobile.

For example, I have sites like www.abc.com, www.cde.com, www.fgh.com etc all poiting to same codebase and a common database of a Drupal multisiste installation which uses Domain Access Module as its key module. Whats the best way to make a multisite Drupal installation also accessible via mobile. So now I would like www.abc.com when accessed via mobile to show the mobile version or get redirected to mobile.abc.com

1. Use Mobify.me and associate plugin
2. Use Drupal Mobile Plugin http://drupal.org/project/mobileplugin
3. Make a page in php using Drupal database.

The mobile version just needs to show the last 3 items while the web version is a complex magazine layout.

Whats the best solution considering the following points

1. flexibility
2. low server load
3. fast response time
4. reliability

Alternate solutions are also welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a good overview of options [here](http://www.mobiledrupal.com/content/overview-mobile-modules-drupal)

Option 1 and 3 are fails when it comes to most of your criteria.

[Mobile Tools](http://drupal.org/project/mobile_tools) seems better supported and used than mobileplugin, but it is probably worth experimenting a bit to see what works best in your environemnt.

Comment: I did not use Mobile Tools. Rather, I used separate page tpls for mobile device. That served my purpose for now! :)